# Need to replace value in dictionary in destination file with the value in the dictionary in source file

Tags: json, list, dictionary, ansible, ansible-2.x

I have been trying to update the values in a dictionary in destination json with the values in the dictionary in source JSON file. Below is the example of source and destination JSON file:

Source file:

```json
[
        {
                "key": "MYSQL",
                "value": "456"
        },
        {
                "key": "RDS",
                "value": "123"
        }
]
```

Destination File:

```json
[
        {
                "key": "MYSQL",
                "value": "100"
        },
        {
                "key": "RDS",
                "value": "111"
        },
        {
                "key": "DB1",
                "value": "TestDB"
        },
        {
                "key": "OS",
                "value": "EX1"
        }
]
```

Expectation in destination file after running Ansible playbook:

```json
[
        {
                "key": "MYSQL",
                "value": "**456**"
        },
        {
                "key": "RDS",
                "value": "**123**"
        },
        {
                "key": "DB1",
                "value": "TestDB"
        },
        {
                "key": "OS",
                "value": "EX1"
        }
]
```

Below is the playbook I have tried so far, but this only updates the value if it is hard coded:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:

  - name: Parse JSON
    shell: cat Source.json
    register: result

  - name: Save json data to a variable
    set_fact:
      jsondata: "{{result.stdout | from_json}}"

  - name: Get key names
    set_fact:
      json_key: "{{ jsondata | map(attribute='key') | flatten }}"

  - name: Get Values names
    set_fact:
      json_value: "{{ jsondata | map(attribute='value') | flatten }}"

  # Trying to update the destination file with only the values provided in source.json
  - name: Replace values in json
    replace:
      path: Destination.json
      regexp: '"{{ item }}": "100"'
      replace: '"{{ item }}": "456"'
    loop:
    - value
```

The main goal is to update the `value` in *destination.json* with the `value` provided in *source.json*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ansible, the couple `key`/`value` tends to be handled with the filters [`dict2items`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-dictionaries-into-lists) and [`items2dict`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-lists-into-dictionaries). And your use case can be handled by those filters.

Here would be the logic:

- Read both files
- Convert both files into dictionaries, with `dict2items`
- Combine the two dictionaries, with the [`combine`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) filter
- Convert the dictionary back into a list with `items2dict`
- Dump the result in JSON back into the file

---

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - shell: cat Source.json
      register: source

    - shell: cat Destination.json
      register: destination

    - copy:
        content: "{{ 
            destination.stdout | from_json | items2dict | 
            combine(
              source.stdout | from_json | items2dict
            ) | dict2items | to_nice_json
          }}"
        dest: Destination.json
```

We end up with *Destination.json* containing:

```json
[
    {
        "key": "MYSQL",
        "value": "456"
    },
    {
        "key": "RDS",
        "value": "123"
    },
    {
        "key": "DB1",
        "value": "TestDB"
    },
    {
        "key": "OS",
        "value": "EX1"
    }
]
```

Comment: Hi, How can we format/pretty print the json in the destination.json file?

Comment: @Zeeshan This was due to the use of the YAML folding style `>-`, [the updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70059041/revisions) shows you how to keep a pretty formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Without to knowing the structure of your destination file it's difficult to use a regex.
I suggest you to load your destination file in a variable, do the changes and save the content of variable to file.

This solution does the job:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:

    - name: Parse JSON
      set_fact:
        source: "{{ lookup('file', 'source.json') | from_json }}"
        destination: "{{ lookup('file', 'destination.json') | from_json }}"

    - name: create new json
      set_fact:
        json_new: "{{ json_new | d([]) + ([item] if _rec == [] else [_rec]) | flatten }}"
      loop: "{{ destination }}"
      vars:
        _rec: "{{ source | selectattr('key', 'equalto', item.key) }}"


    - name: save new json
      copy:
        content: "{{ json_new | to_nice_json }}"
        dest: dest_new.json
```

Result -> dest_new.json:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "key": "MYSQL",
            "value": "456"
        },
        {
            "key": "RDS",
            "value": "123"
        },
        {
            "key": "DB1",
            "value": "TestDB"
        },
        {
            "key": "OS",
            "value": "EX1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Frenchy, This seems to be working fine, but the output I can see is a generator not a list - TASK [display json_new] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "<generator object select_or_reject at 0x7f9f78841550>"
    ]
}.   If I try to filter the selectattr with the list it is getting converted to list but  I can only see the last element in json_new, not the entire list of dictionaries. How do I convert this to a list - json_new?

Comment: This is how am trying to convert a generator object to list -  vars:
      _rec: "{{ result | selectattr('key', 'equalto', item.key) | list}}".   How do I convert the entire json_new to list.

Comment: sorry i dont understand your problem, i have edited my answer with the full code and i have not the problem you describe....  the file saved is in nice json format with the result waited...

Comment: As I was using a older version, I was getting output as Generator  object instead of list. I have now updated to the latest version on ansible and your solutions works as expected. Thanks!!

Comment: @Zeeshan ok i understant why i have not the same problem!! glad to help you